# To print each alphabet using ascii numbers in a pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this problem, I want to print a letter in each row based on the row it is in. It will also depend on the size of the pattern. But when I run this program, none of the letters are getting printed (where the desired output is letters in the middle column based on the row); only `-` are getting printed.

What am I doing wrong?

```py
def print_rangoli(size):
    row=2*size - 1
    col=4*size - 3
    for i in range(0,row):
        for j in range(0,col):
            if  j==col/2:
                print(chr(96+n-i),end='')
            else:
                print("-",end='')
        print(" ")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print_rangoli(n)
```

Expected output is:

```
--------e--------
--------d--------
--------c--------
--------b--------
--------a--------
```

and so on.

But the actual output is:

```
-----------------
-----------------
-----------------
-----------------
-----------------
-----------------
-----------------
-----------------
-----------------
```

Comment: Maybe you would like to check `str.center(n, fill)` or [`'{:-^size}'.format(str)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) for padding instead of using fors.

Comment: `col` is always odd, so `col/2` will never be equal to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, unlike in other languages, sign ‘/‘ does not refer to integer division. In your case, variable `col` is odd number. And inside of for loop, you are checking: `if j == col / 2`. As `col` is odd, division to 2 will be float number (and your `j` never is float). If you want to do integer division, so that you find middle of row, try `//` operation, which refers to integer division.